# combination of traveling salesman with knapsack

Tags: algorithms, optimization, knapsack-problems, traveling-salesman

I am trying to create an optimisation process for a variant of the travelling salesman problem which is combined with a knapsack problem in the following way:

Let there be a set of points $P$ on a two-dimensional grid, each point $p$ has a specified weight $w(p)$ and value $v(p)$. A traveller leaves his home village carrying merchandise with a weight limited by a parameter $lim(W)$, sells his merchandise to a subset of the villages and returns home. The goal is to find the subset of points $P\star\subseteq P$ for which the optimised route distance $TSP(P\star)$ maximises $$\frac{\sum_{p\in P\star} v(p)}{TSP(P\star)}$$$$where$$$${\sum_{p\in P\star} w(p)} \le lim(W)$$
I am currently researching for optimisation processes for selecting a subset from a set, given arbitrary cost function and constraints, but couldn't find anything useful. any ideas or links to pieces of literature will be appreciated.